# How do i process multiple if statements in a sinatra post method

Tags: sinatra, checkbox

I am trying to do multiple things based on the values of my checkboxes. I have this on the htlm form :

`<input id="one" checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1">`

`<input id="two" checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2">`

And in Sinatra
post '/process-data' do
    one = params[:one]
    two = params[:two]

```
   if one = "1"
    "One"
   end
   if two = "2"
    "Two"
   end
```

end

I am unable to get the result from second if statement, my question is, how do i get Sinatra to be able to get the values from the second if.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
"One" if one == "1"
"Two" if two == "2"
```

You're using `=` rather than `==` or `===`.